# Copy and Delete Rows from sheet to multiple sheets in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Master sheet and other Sheets and they have the 1st 2 columns containing the unique ID of my items (column A) and the Item names (column B).
I want my colleagues to update only with Master sheet with their IDs and Item names so that:

- when you delete both the IDs and item names in the Master sheet also all other sheets would be affected, that is all IDs and Item names will need to be deleted
- when they copy the new IDs and items names in the Master sheet, also all other sheets are updated accordingly

I wrote the below code but something strange happens when I delete the IDs and Items (only the 1st 2 rows are deleted in all other sheets and the header of the Master sheet is added in row number 1). When Master sheet is empty and I copy both the IDs and the Items name, the code seems to work.
I am missing something that I cannot understand:

```
Sub CopyAndDeleteList()
Dim sourceWs As Worksheet, destinationWs As Worksheet, destinationLastRow As Long
Set sourceWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
Set destinationWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheetName")
destinationLastRow = sourceWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Call sourceWs.Range("A2:A" & destinationLastRow).Copy(destinationWs.Range("A3"))
Call sourceWs.Range("B2:B" & destinationLastRow).Copy(destinationWs.Range("B3"))
End Sub
```

I then added the above into the Master sheet change event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:B100")) Is Nothing Then
    
      Call CopyAndDeleteList
End If
End Sub
```

Here are some screenshots:

This is the Master sheet example when data has been pasted from an external source:

[image: This the Master sheet example when data has been pasted from an external source]

One data is pasted here the code is ran and then data is automatically pasted in Sheet1 too.

However, when I have to change my ID (because the file is used by another user or because my clients change) first thing I do is to delete the old IDs in the Master sheet and this is what happens in Sheet1:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: If the first column contains unique values, why are you mentioning the names that much? What does deleting Ids and names mean? Do you mean deleting the entire row or are those two the only columns on each worksheet? Are the other worksheets named after the Ids or names i.e. how do I know to which worksheet to copy a new Id and name? Please do clarify and also add some screenshots of the worksheets.

Comment: Hi here are the answers: because I need both the IDs and the Clients' names. It means that since files is used by many people, each one has his/her own clients before adding their own clients they need to cancel the old ones. I mean deleting all the values contained in the rows. No, worksheets are not named after the IDs or names. You know where to copy because this is explicit in the code. Basically I need the IDs and names in other 10 sheets because they show us the progression of a client VS a particular product over time (this is updated weekly). Hope this is clearer.

Comment: Just curious, is row 2 (column A and B) in your sheet 1 originally blank ? Or originally has a value - that's why the copy destination is in row 3?

Comment: Maybe it is because when  you delete the whole data in your master sheet (you just leave the header), it will copy the header and one blank row below it (row 2) ---> then paste it in row 3 of sheet 1. That's why you see the header is double in sheet 1 and it doesn't delete the remaining rows in sheet 1, because what you paste is only two rows, one row with the header and a row below it which is blank.

Comment: Maybe try to clear column A and B of sheet1 firat before your `copy:destination` code line

Answer (score 0):

I made it, here is the code for future reference:

```
Sub CopyList()
Dim sourceWs As Worksheet, destinationWs As Worksheet, destinationLastRow As Long
Set sourceWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
Set destinationWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
destinationLastRow = sourceWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Call sourceWs.Range("A2:A" & destinationLastRow).Copy(destinationWs.Range("A2"))
Call sourceWs.Range("B2:B" & destinationLastRow).Copy(destinationWs.Range("B2"))
End Sub
Sub DeleteList()
Dim destinationWs As Worksheet, destinationLastRow As Long
Set destinationWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
destinationLastRow = destinationWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
destinationWs.Range("A2:B" & destinationLastRow).ClearContents
End Sub
```

And in Master:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim UndoList As String
UndoList = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
If Left(UndoList, 5) = "Paste" Then
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:B100")) Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Copied"
Call CopyList
Exit Sub
End If
ElseIf WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Target) = Target.Cells.Count Then
MsgBox "Deleted"
Call DeleteList
Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```